# how to disable debug assert message or redirect message to console in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, assert

when try to run wxPython's GUI construction and event loop in a separate thread, I have an issue that when the application closed, there will be a debug alert message shown up, see the image:

[image: debug alert]

Is there any way to redirect those popped up message to console? Or just disable those alert warning messages?

I found that there is a function [DisableAsserts()](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/functions.html#DisableAsserts), but I don't know how to call this function from python script, does this function exported from C++?

There is another kind of function [app.SetAssertMode()](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.PyApp-class.html#SetAssertMode), but I tested it and found it does not have any affect on disable or redirect the alert message.

I would like your suggestion to solve this problem, thanks.

BTW, a detailed description why I need to run wxPython in a separate thread can be found [alert message pops up when I close a console application if I run wxPython app.MainLoop() in a seperate thread - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/sQp7ijJrqI0)

EDIT:
I found that using separate wxPython Gui thread under GDB's python interface is a mass. I can avoid the debug alert message by using an old version of wxPython2.8.12. For GDB, I need to define a custom command in `def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):`, which will be called if I type the custom command. Once I type the command, a new thread runs, and some wxPython GUIs are constructed, and the thread is goes to Mainloop. If I close the Gui Window, the Thread's run function just finished, but for some unknown reason, sometimes, the thread object does not destroyed immediately. If I run the custom command again, sometimes, GDB just crashes, or a new window can shown, but I see that the print command's contents will go to it's own window, not the GDB's stdout or stderr, see screen shot below.
[image: some new wxPython stdout and stderr window jump up]

I believe using wxPython GUI in a separate thread is still not quite stable here. Here is my testing code if you want to try.

```
import gdb

import sys

import threading
from threading import Thread
import ctypes

# Used to guarantee to use at least Wx2.8
import wxversion
wxversion.ensureMinimal('2.8')

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# uncomment the following to use wx rather than wxagg
#matplotlib.use('WX')
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import FigureCanvasWx as FigureCanvas

# comment out the following to use wx rather than wxagg
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx

from matplotlib.figure import Figure


from numpy import arange, sin, pi

import wx

class CanvasFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,
                         'CanvasFrame',size=(550,350))

        self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.NamedColour("WHITE"))

        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)

        self.axes.plot(t,s)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.add_toolbar()  # comment this out for no toolbar


    def add_toolbar(self):
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Wx(self.canvas)
        self.toolbar.Realize()
        if wx.Platform == '__WXMAC__':
            # Mac platform (OSX 10.3, MacPython) does not seem to cope with
            # having a toolbar in a sizer. This work-around gets the buttons
            # back, but at the expense of having the toolbar at the top
            self.SetToolBar(self.toolbar)
        else:
            # On Windows platform, default window size is incorrect, so set
            # toolbar width to figure width.
            tw, th = self.toolbar.GetSizeTuple()
            fw, fh = self.canvas.GetSizeTuple()
            # By adding toolbar in sizer, we are able to put it at the bottom
            # of the frame - so appearance is closer to GTK version.
            # As noted above, doesn't work for Mac.
            self.toolbar.SetSize(wx.Size(fw, th))
            self.sizer.Add(self.toolbar, 0, wx.LEFT | wx.EXPAND)
        # update the axes menu on the toolbar
        self.toolbar.update()


    def OnPaint(self, event):
        self.canvas.draw()

class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        'Create the main window and insert the custom frame'
        frame = CanvasFrame()
        whnd = frame.GetHandle()
        # SW_SHOW = 5, so we force to set on the WS_VISIBLE window style, see below as a reference
        # Window Styles (Windows) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx
        # ShowWindow function (Windows) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
        ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow(whnd, 5) 
        frame.Show(True)
        return True



class MyThread (threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, thread_id = None, name = None, image = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.app = None
        self.start()

    def __del__(self):
        print "MyThrad dead"
        #ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, 'MyThread dead', 'Window title', 0)

    def run(self):
        self.app = MyApp(False)
        self.app.MainLoop()
        #ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, 'Main loop finish', 'Window title', 0)
        print "MyThread run() finish"

    def set_image(self, image):
        self.image = image
        print "image set/updated"


class PlotterCommand(gdb.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PlotterCommand, self).__init__("plot",
                                             gdb.COMMAND_DATA,
                                             gdb.COMPLETE_SYMBOL)
        print "Constructor of Plotter object"
        self.thread1 = None
        sys.stdout.flush()

    def __del__( self ):  
        print 'Destructor of Plotter object' 
        sys.stdout.flush()


    def invoke(self, arg, from_tty):
        #args = gdb.string_to_argv(arg)
        # generally, we type "plot someVar" in the GDB commandline
        #v = gdb.parse_and_eval(args[0])
        # do something with the v object

        thread1 = MyThread(1, "Thread 1", None)

        print "Finish invoke plot command"
        sys.stdout.flush()

PlotterCommand()
```

Save the above code as "my.py", when debugging under GDB, you can type the command `source my.py` to load those python code, and now you have a new command named `plot`, you can type `plot` in the GDB, a wxPython window will show up. You can close the Window, and type `plot` again, then problem will happen. Or, you can leave the window, and just type `plot` , you will get more errors.

**EDIT2**
The "stdout/stderr" window problem is fixed, I can just pass the `self.app = MyApp(False)` to disable this log window.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to ensure that the assert doesn't happen? Why are you using sockets at all here?

Comment: Hi, VZ. I never use socket. I run the wxPython GUI under GDB's command line as a GDB pretty printer to visualize some data. So, why wxWidgets call socket related function when GDB exits? Maybe, GDB has already open some socket? But I use GDB.exe to debug a local exe file, I never use GDB to connect remote GDBserver.